# Msal authentication hosted in AAD B2C doesn't auto refresh token after update from 3.1 to 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Everything works fine as long as you don't use our application for more than 55 minutes after logging in without refresh. After that the customer is unable to communicate with our api's. I have it configured like this:

Portal Azure sign in flow:
[Screenshot sign in flow properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMtuy.png)

Program.cs

```
      builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://test.onmicrosoft.com/61111111e-1111-1111-bbbb-111111111111/API.access");
                }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, UserFactory>();

      builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Test.Api", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)).AddHttpMessageHandler<TestAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
      builder.Services.AddHttpClient<CustomerOrdersClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)).AddHttpMessageHandler<TetsAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

AuthorizationMessageHandler:

```
 public class TestaAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
    {
        public TestAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, NavigationManager navigationManager) : base(provider, navigationManager)
        {
            ConfigureHandler(authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:5001", "https://localhost:44360", "https://app.test.nl", "https://test-api-prod-aa.azurewebsites.net" });
        }
    }
```

The client I use for this test. It works fine as long as the accesstoken doesnt expire.

```
 public class ShipmentsClient : IClient<Shipment>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private readonly string _endpoint = " api/shipments";

        public ShipmentsClient(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }
        public async Task<List<Shipment>> GetAsync()
        {
            var shipments = new List<Shipment>();

            try
            {
                shipments = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Shipment>>(_endpoint);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                shipments = new List<Shipment>();
        }

            return shipments;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you attaching the token to your HttpClient's requests?

Comment: @AkinzeKeel wIth the AuthorizationMessageHandler